# store a binary search tree graph into an array using recursion and print it out

Tags: java, exception, binary-search-tree

I already build a binary search tree. The primitive data type I store in the tree is integer. I try to store it on a 2-D char array and then print it out as the graph shown below(the numbers represent row numbers and column numbers and I do not need to print it, ignoring "-" symbol please, I only use it to indicate the exact position)

```
-----0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9---10---11---12---13---14---15---16

0---------------------------------------12                             

1--------------------------------/-------------------\

2----------------------8--------------------------------------14

3-----------------/----------\ -----------------------------------------\

4-------------5----------------9-------------------------------------------34

5--------/-------------------------------------------------------------/-------------\

6---2---------------------------------------------------------24------------------------35
```

number 12 need to store on location [0][8], the middle of the first row. 
number 4 store on[2][4], number 14=[2][12], 5=[4][2], 9=[4][9] and so on.

row number 1 which is second row, "/" is on position[1][6] and "\" is on position[1][10] etc.they are also on the middle between two numbers

following is my code

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //level represents row number;
        // start indicates the column I am going to 
        //store number in, and end is a fixed column number
        // BinarySearchTree is a BinaryTree type instance,
        // I already story integers on it and follow with the format
        // of binary search trees, and I did tested it.
        int level=0; int start=0; int end=80;
        BinaryTree.plot(BinarySearchTree, level, start, end);
    }

private static class BinaryTree {

    private BinaryNode root;
    static char[][] offset = new char [10][20];

    public BinaryTree(){
        root = null;
    }

    public BinaryTree(Object x){
        root = new BinaryNode(x);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return root == null;
    }  

    public Object getRootobj() throws BinaryTreeException{
        if(root == null) 
            throw new BinaryTreeException("Empty Tree");
        else
            return root.element;
    }

    public BinaryTree getLeft() throws BinaryTreeException{
        if(root == null)
            throw new BinaryTreeException("Empty Tree");
        else {
            BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree();
            t.root = root.left;
            return t;
        }
    }

    public BinaryTree getRight() throws BinaryTreeException{
        if(root == null)
            throw new BinaryTreeException("Empty Tree");
        else {
            BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree();
            t.root = root.right;
            return t;
        }
    }

    public static void plot(BinaryTree t, int level, int start, int end){
        if(!t.isEmpty()){
            plot(t.getLeft(), level+2, start/2, end/2);
            String string = Integer.toString((Integer)t.getRootobj());
            for(char c: string.toCharArray())
                offset[level][start++]=c;
            if(!(t.getLeft().isEmpty()))
                offset[++level][start/4*3] = '/';
            if(!(t.getRight().isEmpty()))
                offset[++level][((start+end)/2+start)/2] = '\\';
                plot(t.getRight(), level+2, end/2, end);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            for(int j= 0; j<20; j++)
                System.out.print(offset[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

private static class BinaryNode {

    Object element;
    BinaryNode left,right;

    BinaryNode() {
        this(0);
    }

    BinaryNode(Object e) {
        this(e, null, null);
    }

    BinaryNode(Object e, BinaryNode ln, BinaryNode m){
        element=e;
        left=ln;
        right=m;
    }
}
}
```

Question: the method plot I used to store and print out binarysearchtree did not work, which causes a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

can anyone take a look at it. appreciated for the help.

Comment: If you get an exception, always add the stacktrace!

Comment: Please include a sample code for creating your BinarySearchTree instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed-size char-Array cannot cope with your dynamic sized BinaryTree. For your given example alone you need way more then 20 characters per line! That's where your Exception is coming from.

But to give you an idea of an alternative approach - even though it took a while, made the following additions to your code:

---

First, I added a method to the `BinaryNode` class:

```
int getDepth() {
    int subTreeDepth;
    if (left == null && right == null) {
        subTreeDepth = 0;
    } else if (left == null) {
        subTreeDepth = right.getDepth();
    } else if (right == null) {
        subTreeDepth = left.getDepth();
    } else {
        subTreeDepth = Math.max(left.getDepth(), right.getDepth());
    }
    return 1 + subTreeDepth;
}
```

Second, I removed your fixed char-Array and replaced the whole plotting algorithm in your `BinaryTree` (I just couldn't wrap my head around all those relative array-index manipulations):

```
public void plot() {
    if (root == null) {
        throw new BinaryTreeException("Empty Tree");
    }
    int lineCount = 2 * root.getDepth() - 1;
    StringBuilder[] lines = new StringBuilder[lineCount];
    for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lineCount; lineIndex++) {
        lines[lineIndex] = new StringBuilder();
    }
    // get the right most node (which contains the largest element value)
    BinaryNode rightMostNode = root;
    while (rightMostNode.right != null) {
        rightMostNode = rightMostNode.right;
    }
    // check how many characters we have to reserve for a single node element
    int maxElementLength = String.valueOf(rightMostNode.element).length();
    plot(root, 0, 0, maxElementLength, lines);
    for (StringBuilder singleLine : lines) {
        System.out.println(singleLine.toString());
    }
}

private void plot(BinaryNode subTreeRoot, int offset, int lineIndex, int elementLength, StringBuilder[] lines) {
    int actualOffset;
    if (subTreeRoot.left == null) {
        actualOffset = offset;
    } else {
        actualOffset = offset + (int) Math.pow(2, subTreeRoot.left.getDepth() - 1) * elementLength;
    }
    StringBuilder currentLine = lines[lineIndex];
    String elementValue = String.valueOf(subTreeRoot.element);
    for (int lineFillIndex = currentLine.length() + elementValue.length() / 2; lineFillIndex < actualOffset; lineFillIndex++) {
        currentLine.append(' ');
    }
    currentLine.append(elementValue);
    if (subTreeRoot.left != null) {
        // draw connection to left sub tree
        int connectPosition = (actualOffset - offset) * 3 / 4 + offset;
        StringBuilder connectLine = lines[lineIndex + 1];
        for (int lineFillIndex = connectLine.length(); lineFillIndex < connectPosition; lineFillIndex++) {
            connectLine.append(' ');
        }
        connectLine.append('/');
        // insert the left part of the next value line
        plot(subTreeRoot.left, offset, lineIndex + 2, elementLength, lines);
    }
    if (subTreeRoot.right != null) {
        // draw connection to right sub tree
        int connectPosition = actualOffset + elementLength - elementValue.length() / 2;
        if (subTreeRoot.right.left != null) {
            connectPosition += (int) Math.pow(2, subTreeRoot.right.left.getDepth() - 1) * elementLength / 2;
        }
        StringBuilder connectLine = lines[lineIndex + 1];
        for (int lineFillIndex = connectLine.length(); lineFillIndex < connectPosition; lineFillIndex++) {
            connectLine.append(' ');
        }
        connectLine.append('\\');
        // insert the right part of the next value line
        plot(subTreeRoot.right, actualOffset + elementLength, lineIndex + 2, elementLength, lines);
    }
}
```

For a tree similar to the one, you included in your question:

```
BinaryTree binarySearchTree = new BinaryTree(
        new BinaryNode(12, 
                new BinaryNode(8,
                        new BinaryNode(5,
                                new BinaryNode(3),
                                null),
                        new BinaryNode(9)),
                new BinaryNode(14,
                        null,
                        new BinaryNode(34,
                                new BinaryNode(24),
                                new BinaryNode(35)))));
binarySearchTree.plot();
```

I get the following output:

```
       12
      /  \
    8    14
   /  \     \
  5   9      34
 /           / \
3          24  35
```